# Pseudo random binary sequences (prbs) in Python

Tags: python, random, signals

How can I make a *pseudo random binary sequence* (prbs) signal through Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> def prbs():
...     while True:
...         yield choice([False, True])
```

Comment: This is not a PRBS generator.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a basic implementation for prbs31 with monic polynomial:
x<sup>31</sup> + x<sup>28</sup> + 1

```
def prbs31(code):
    for i in range(32):
        next_bit = ~((code>>30) ^ (code>>27))&0x01
        code = ((code<<1) | next_bit) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    return code
```

Given an integer, the function will generate PRBS sequence a bit at a time and return an integer containing the next 32 bits of the sequence. Note the input integer's bits above x<sup>31</sup> are irrelevant to the output.

XOR and negation are used to perform bit-wise (modulo 2) addition. This probably won't improve performance in the above code, but you can use the bit arithmetic to compute code at a time for faster performance. e.g.:

```
def prbs31_fast(code):
    next_code = (~((code<<1)^(code<<4)) & 0xFFFFFFF0)
    next_code |= (~(( (code<<1 & 0x0E) | (next_code>>31 & 0x01)) ^ (next_code>>28)) & 0x0000000F)
    return next_code
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. What's the repetition period for prbs31?

Comment: The answer to my question is on [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_binary_sequence): 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the below code. It's a little bit crude but you can get an idea of how to create ***random signals*** and ***PRBS*** using NumPy.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nstep = 300

# random signal generation

a_range = [0,2]
a = np.random.rand(nstep) * (a_range[1]-a_range[0]) + a_range[0] # range for amplitude

b_range = [2, 10]
b = np.random.rand(nstep) *(b_range[1]-b_range[0]) + b_range[0] # range for frequency
b = np.round(b)
b = b.astype(int)

b[0] = 0

for i in range(1,np.size(b)):
    b[i] = b[i-1]+b[i]

# Random Signal
i=0
random_signal = np.zeros(nstep)
while b[i]<np.size(random_signal):
    k = b[i]
    random_signal[k:] = a[i]
    i=i+1

# PRBS
a = np.zeros(nstep)
j = 0
while j < nstep:
    a[j] = 5
    a[j+1] = -5
    j = j+2

i=0
prbs = np.zeros(nstep)
while b[i]<np.size(prbs):
    k = b[i]
    prbs[k:] = a[i]
    i=i+1

plt.figure(0) 
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(random_signal, drawstyle='steps',label='Random Signal')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(prbs, drawstyle='steps', label='PRBS')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]